# C++ - Back Substitution via Boost - Bad Index Error

Tags: c++, algorithm, boost, linear-algebra, numerical-analysis

I have the following code for a back substitution algorithm:

```
#include <boost\numeric\ublas\matrix.hpp>
typedef boost::numeric::ublas::matrix<double> dM;
dM bSub(dM A, dM b)
{
    unsigned int n = (int)b.size1();
    assert(b.size2() == 1);
    assert(n == A.size1());
    dM x(n, 1);
    for (unsigned i = (n - 1); i >= 0; --i)
    {
        double sum = 0.0;
        for (unsigned j = (n - 1); j > i; --j)
        {
            sum += A(i, j)*x(j, 0);
        }
        x(i, 0) = (b(i, 0) - sum) / A(i, i);
    }

    return x;
}
```

A bad index error pops up when I try to run it. I am not quite sure where the error is as I can't find the problem when I am manually going through the algo.

I have also tried incrementing the nested loop: `for(unsigned j = 0; j < n; ++j)`. Again, I run into the same bad index error.

Based on the debugger, I think the problem has to do with `i` somehow taking on a value of 4294967295, I am not sure where that number could come from as it doesn't really fit in other parts of my code.

Lastly, I have also written a forward substitution algo, using a very similar structure, which runs without a problem.

Anyone have an idea what's going on?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The condition `i>=0` is **always** true for `unsigned` types of `i`.

If you compile with warnings (`-Wall -Wextra -pedantic` on your GCC/Clang) then the compiler would tell you this.